# React Navigation how to hide tabbar top-border on a individual screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

It is easy to hide the border on every Screen by doing the following code on Navigator level

```
<Tab.Navigator
   tabBarOptions={{
      style: {
         borderTopWidth: 0,
      },
   }}
>
```

But how to hide the border on a single Screen?
I've already tried the following but it has no effect

```
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
   navigation.setOptions({
      tabBarOptions: {
         style: {
            borderTopWidth: 0,
         },
      },
   });
}, [navigation]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`@react-navigation^v6.x` you need to add `tabBarStyle: { borderTopWidth: 0, elevation: 0}` in the `screenOptions` prop to hide top border in bottom tab bar for both ios and android.

For example:

```js
<Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarStyle: {
          borderTopWidth: 0,
          elevation: 0,
        },
      }}>
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

If we would like to make changes from the child component then we have to access the parent component navigation props.

Have a try with the below code which might help you:

```
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
   navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().setOptions({
      tabBarOptions: {
         style: {
            borderTopWidth: 0,
         },
      },
   });
}, [navigation]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing happened :/

Comment: Have you tried to console.log the navigation.dangerouslyGetParent()?
Does it show any navigation options?

Comment: Object {
  "addListener": [Function addListener],
  "canGoBack": [Function canGoBack],
  "dangerouslyGetParent": [Function dangerouslyGetParent],
  "dangerouslyGetState": [Function anonymous],
  "dispatch": [Function dispatch],
  "goBack": [Function anonymous],
  "isFocused": [Function isFocused],

Comment: "jumpTo": [Function anonymous],
  "navigate": [Function anonymous],
  "pop": [Function anonymous],
  "popToTop": [Function anonymous],
  "push": [Function anonymous],
  "removeListener": [Function removeListener],
  "replace": [Function anonymous],
  "reset": [Function anonymous],
  "setOptions": [Function setOptions],
  "setParams": [Function anonymous],
}